# Can't launch the ios application using ios-deploy

Tags: ios, iphone, continuous-integration, phonegap-cli

I am using this command - 
./ios-deploy --id "+ Device1_Id + " --justlaunch --bundle "+ DownLoadDirectory +"Payload/JARVIS-iOS.app"+" --args 148.147.230.90"

I always get the following error - 
ios-deploy[43742:618752] [ !! ] Error 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)

I am not sure why it says identity is no longer valid, i can of course build the application via Xcode.

Any help is greatly appreciated!! I am using ios-deploy version 2.0.0

Comment: and how you're getting the app? this issue is regarding provisioning profile, I've managed to solve similar problem for cordova project